# How to enable zoom in/out and zoom to percentage buttons in Plots pane in Spyder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ide, spyder

The `zoom in`, `zoom out` and `zoom to percentage` buttons are disabled in *Plots* pane in *Spyder*
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46NKN.png). Any idea how to enable them?

The should be enabled [as seen here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22970578/53638418-8315fe00-3c69-11e9-8f15-f3280ddc1400.png).

#### Specs

Spyder version: 4.0.0
OS: elementary OS
Python: 3.7.5 64-bit
Kernel: Linux 5.4.7-050407-generic
Laptop: Thinkpad E585

### Failed attempts

Following changes in `preferences` didn't help:
 1. Changing `Backend` from *inline* to *automatic*.
 2. Changing `Format` from *png* to *svg*.
 3. Changing `Resolution` from *72* to *150* dpi.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To be able to use those buttons you need to deactivate the option called `Fit plots to window`, present in the Options menu of the Plots pane:

[image: Plots options menu]

Comment: This is counter-intuitive, zooming and fitting to window should not be mutually exclusive. "Fit plots to window" should be the default when loading a plot, zooming should be allowed at all times, and there should be an easily accessible "Fit to window" button that is not hidden in a menu but directly next to the zoom buttons.

Comment: Totally agree with @PoorYorick . It is super wrong that the unique visible button referring to zooming are deactivated and the unique button that activates them is hide to the user view. That makes no sense. There are 2 points here: Fit plots to window button can't be hidden and it can't block the zooming buttons. Spyder plots have to do at least what matlab plot do.  We need a minimal of interactions with our plots.

Comment: @AdolfoCorrea, we're aware of that and we'll try to fix it in a future version. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to ask for the fix in the github [issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9424#issue-448375743)

Comment: The plot is only showing a static PNG (bitmap), not an "interactive" plot!  Zooming into a plot should keep the axes visible etc - that is NOT the same as zooming into a bitmap (where you lose visibility of the axes).  This is a fairly poor plotting capability unless it's interactive.

Comment: @Demis, that's how that pane works, i.e. it's only able to display static images.

Comment: Fine- that's how it currently works - but then it's really just an Image Display pane, not a Plotting pane in this case.  Anything called "Graphing" should really allow for zoom/pan otherwise it's a major downgrade from the normal MPL interactive figure. - sorry to say so, I'm sure you worked hard on it.